# How to proxy socket.io in API gateway developed in LoopBack 4?

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, api-gateway, loopback4

I'm developing an API Gateway on top of the LoopBack 4 microframework. Although service-proxy can easily proxy REST routes, I'm in demand of proxying socket.io requests to the services.

How can I proxy the socket.io in the API Gateway to its destination service in LoopBack 4?

Comment: Instead of building your own API Gateway, would you consider using Amazon API Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/?

Comment: We are using GCloud API Gateway for our public services, however, some of our customers need to deploy the product on their own servers. @Diana

Comment: In which language are you building the API gateway ? NodeJS, Loopback or something else ?

Comment: LoopBack is a NodeJS framework.